# Finding out why disk goes read only oncec a week

Tags: ssd, read-only

Once per week it seems this ssd goes into read only mode. It seems like its always Sunday but I can not 100% confirm that at this point. Is there any place I should look to see whats kicking it into read only?

Running `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`

Here is the output from `dmesg | grep -i 'mount'`

```
[    0.127427] Mount-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.127451] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    2.923738] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    3.305534] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.306844] systemd[1]: Mounting Huge Pages File System...
[    3.307557] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    3.308408] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    3.309511] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[    3.316394] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    3.319664] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    3.319789] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    3.319898] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[    3.320106] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[    3.331875] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
[    3.333993] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[    3.362611] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    3.363770] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
[    3.365921] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    3.369316] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[    3.397687] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for bare, revision 5...
[    3.399068] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core18, revision 2128...
[    3.400368] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core18, revision 2253...
[    3.402429] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core20, revision 1270...
[    3.403942] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 72...
[    3.405876] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 77...
[    3.408791] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gnome-3-38-2004, revision 87...
[    3.410177] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1515...
[    3.411536] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1519...
[    3.415038] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for snap-store, revision 547...
[    3.417231] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for snap-store, revision 558...
[    3.420108] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for snapd, revision 12704...
[    3.422536] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for snapd, revision 14295...
```

Here is `smartctl`

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       SPCC M.2 PCIe SSD
Serial Number:                      11111111111111111111
Firmware Version:                   EDFM20.0
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1987
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x6479a7
Total NVM Capacity:                 256,060,514,304 [256 GB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      1
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          256,060,514,304 [256 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            6479a7 5580500da2
Local Time is:                      Tue Jan 11 11:09:08 2022 EST
Firmware Updates (0x12):            1 Slot, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005e):     Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         64 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     70 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     80 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     4.50W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     2.70W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     2.16W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3     1000    1000
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     5000  100000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         1
 1 -    4096       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        23 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          5%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    26,898 [13.7 GB]
Data Units Written:                 77,333 [39.5 GB]
Host Read Commands:                 358,393
Host Write Commands:                1,697,160
Controller Busy Time:               33
Power Cycles:                       18
Power On Hours:                     207
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   13
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      12
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               35 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 16 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

Here is the output from `journalctl`

```
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:00:1d.0: [8086:9d18] type 01 class 0x060400
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:00:1d.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:03:00.0: [1987:5013] type 00 class 0x010802
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:03:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xef000000-0xef003fff 64bit]
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:03:00.0: 15.752 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 8.0 GT/s PCIe x2 link at 0000:00:1d.0 (capable of 31.504 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s P>
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:00:1d.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:00:1d.0:   bridge window [mem 0xef000000-0xef0fffff]
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:00:1d.0: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pci 0000:00:1d.0:   bridge window [mem 0xef000000-0xef0fffff]
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 124
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: pcieport 0000:00:1d.0: AER: enabled with IRQ 124
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:03:00.0
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: nvme nvme0: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
Jan 13 10:44:14 hcker2000-s1 kernel: nvme nvme0: allocated 128 MiB host memory buffer.
```

Comment: There may be something in `/var/log/syslog`, but only if the error could be written before the device was remounted as read-only 

Comment: I grepped that for "error" but didnt find anything

Comment: I wouldn't only `grep` for the word error (unless you also scanned lines around the line found); key words can be read-only, mount etc.. but I usually find the issues using date/times because I'm looking the following or a subsequent day with an approximate day & time already known.  Issues tend to stand out anyway; but it's more than just a single word 'error' that I look for.

Comment: Search all the logs `sudo journalctl -b 0 /dev/nvme0n1p2`. Read `man journalct`.

Comment: Thanks I have added the output from journalct from right after a reboot when it has had the error. I tried to find a way to run the command while the disk is read only but no commands will work with it in read only.